# Nuget Package Manager role in ASP .NET?

Tags: asp.net, nuget-package

What is the role of NuGet Package Manager in case of ASP.NET?

Comment: Please provide more detail. Are you encountering a specific problem? What are you trying to do; and why are you trying to use NuGet to do it if you don't know what it does?

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing that can be answered simply by doing some web searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some benifits which i noticed

1. Dependencies of a package will be automatically resolved (you dont
   need to keep a check for anything )
2. NuGet notifies you about available package updates

Some more detailed are identified in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002185/why-we-need-a-package-manager-like-nuget) answer